# Is the function gmp_prob_prime in PHP a bit lack luster?

Tags: php, gmp

Here is a snippet of code where I'm using gmp_prob_prime.  Even though I'm currently only testing numbers in the 10^6 range this function VERY regularly "fails" my QuickTest and ends up needing to do a manual check of $NumberToTest for primality.

Is gmp_prob_prime not very robust?  I didn't expect it to suggest "probable prime" until I was in the 10^9 or even 10^12 range.

Here is the snippet of my code's function that is being called:

```
function IsPrime($DocRoot, $NumberToTest, $PowOf2)
{
// First a quick test...
// 0 = composite
// 1 = probable prime
// 2 = definite prime
$Reps = 15;
$QuickTest = gmp_prob_prime($NumberToTest,$Reps);
if( $QuickTest == 0 )
        {
        return 0;
        }
if ( $QuickTest == 2 )
        {
        return 1;
        }

// If we get to here then gmp_prob_prime isn't sure whether the $NumberToTest is prime or not.
print "Consider increasing the Reps for gmp_prob_prime.\n";

// Find the sqrt of $NumberToTest;
```

... code continues ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior when calling `mpz_probab_prime_p` directly from C++, but I can't recall if the below information fixed it or not ([copied from the manual](https://gmplib.org/manual/Number-Theoretic-Functions.html)).

> Function: int mpz_probab_prime_p (const mpz_t n, int reps)
>
> Determine whether n is prime. Return 2 if n is definitely prime, return 1 if n is probably prime (without being certain), or return 0 if n is definitely composite.
>
> This function does some trial divisions, then some Miller-Rabin probabilistic primality tests. The argument reps controls how many such tests are done; a higher value will reduce the chances of a composite being returned as “probably prime”. 25 is a reasonable number; a composite number will then be identified as a prime with a probability of less than 2^(-50).
>
> Miller-Rabin and similar tests can be more properly called compositeness tests. Numbers which fail are known to be composite but those which pass might be prime or might be composite. Only a few composites pass, hence those which pass are considered probably prime.